# Ubuntu stuck and crash when downloading internet data

Tags: internet, freeze, crash

My Ubuntu freeze (mouse not responding) when I download large files, it happens both from browser and from terminal (wget).

Sometimes it crash and reboot automatically.

I can't complete the **SpeedOf.Me** internet test. It crash at 60%.

I formatted everything and reinstalled a new version of Ubuntu 18, but the problem remains.

I have a dual boot system and Windows 10 works perfectly.

What do you think it can be?

I'm thinking about some hardware failure of the disk.

---

System Model, Dell XPS 15 9560
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 2801 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Dell Inc. 1.3.3, 5/8/2017
16GB RAM
Disco SSD 512 GB

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your computer

You have a very old BIOS version 1.3.3. Current is 1.18.0 and be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/xps-15-9560-laptop/drivers).

**Memory**

Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Disk**

Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` application SMART Data window.

Comment: updating BIOS solved the problem

Comment: @FabioDev Great news! Please remember to remove nomodeset, and to delete your answer, below.